# A procedure with a single parameter but the input values for that parameter are more than one?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to make a procedure have a single parameter but the values for that parameter are more than one?

I have this procedure:

```
Public Sub autoComplete(ByVal cboCombo As ComboBox)
    With cboCombo
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
    End With
End Sub
```

Now I was wondering if there is a way to use it like this:

```
autoComplete(myCombobox1, myCombobox2, myCombobox3)
```

Or can I use a procedure like this with 'With...End With'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a [`ParamArray` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/538f81ec.aspx):

```
Public Sub AutoComplete(ByVal ParamArray boxes As ComboBox())
    For Each box In boxes
        With box
            .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append
            .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a side question, are ParamArray parameters the only arguments you can place in a procedure? Or can I also add a string argument in the same procedure? I tried to add one and it didn't work (Did I just answer my question? lol)

Comment: Read the documentation.  `A procedure can define only one parameter array, and it must be the last parameter in the procedure definition.`